# Tengo un formulario PHP tipo test cuya respuesta vale A, B, C, ¿cómo puedo contabilizar las respuestas almacenadas?

Tags: php, mysql, html5, base-de-datos, formularios

diseñé un formulario, cuyas respuestas se almacenan en Mysql estoy usando PHPMYADMIN, cuando el usuario envía el formulario, se guarda el registro de sus respuestas, pero necesito de su apoyo, porque quiero contabilizar por ejemplo como lo anexo en la imagen:

Respuestas tipo A: 7
Respuestas tipo B: 2
Respuestas tipo C: 1

Y a partir de la respuesta de mayor valor imprimir con un if, por este asunto no tengo detalle, solo quiero ayuda en un método para contabilizar las elecciones del usuario. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Anexo como generé las preguntas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano muchas gracias!

Comment: Para que sea más facil probar para las personas que quieran ayudarte. El código es mejor escribirlo como texto y no un recorte de imagen, ya que permite facilmente copiar y pegar para quien hace pruebas en vez de transcribir todo el código. Probablemente algunos no lo intenten porque transcribir código es poco productivo y tedioso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realmente, tu forma de almacenar la información en la base de datos tiene un pequeño fallo de normalización: deberías utilizar una tabla para registrar los datos de la persona evaluada, otra para las preguntas y otra para sus respuestas. Entonces, resolverías tu problema con una simple consulta de agrupamiento. Otra opción sería realizar ese conteo desde PHP, con un par de bucles que recorran cada usuario y sus respuestas pero, en SQL, no se trabaja así. Se podría, pero no resultaría eficiente para el programador ni para el motor de la base de datos.

Asumiendo, porque no la muestras, que tienes superada la parte donde generas el formulario e insertas los datos en las tablas, te indico cómo crear las tablas, cómo insertar unos datos de prueba y cómo contabilizar las respuestas almacenadas:

```
CREATE TABLE personas(
  id_persona int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre varchar(63),
  apellido varchar(63),
  grupo varchar(7),
  email varchar(63)
  );
CREATE TABLE preguntas(
  id_pregunta int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  pregunta text,
  opcionA text,
  opcionB text,
  opcionC text
  );
CREATE TABLE respuestas(
  id_respuesta int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  fecha_actual datetime,
  id_persona int,
  id_pregunta int,
  opcion char(1),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_pregunta) REFERENCES preguntas(id_pregunta)
  );
```

Inserción de datos de muestra:

```
INSERT INTO personas (nombre, apellido, grupo, email) VALUES
  ('JOSE FERNANDO','LUCIANO GARCIA','D','josep55@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO preguntas (pregunta, opcionA, opcionB, opcionC) VALUES
  ('¿Cuál de las siguientes actividades disfruta más?',
  'Escuchar música','Ver películas','Bailar con buena música'),
  ('P2','A','B','C'),
  ('P3','A','B','C'),
  ('P4','A','B','C'),
  ('P5','A','B','C'),
  ('P6','A','B','C'),
  ('P7','A','B','C'),
  ('P8','A','B','C');
INSERT INTO respuestas (fecha_actual, id_persona, id_pregunta, opcion) VALUES
  (NOW(),1,1,'A'),
  (NOW(),1,2,'A'),
  (NOW(),1,3,'B'),
  (NOW(),1,4,'B'),
  (NOW(),1,5,'A'),
  (NOW(),1,6,'A'),
  (NOW(),1,7,'A'),
  (NOW(),1,8,'A');
```

Consulta de contabilización de resultados:

```
SELECT id_persona,opcion,COUNT(*)
  FROM respuestas
  GROUP BY 1,2
  ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Resultado de la consulta para los datos de muestra propuestos:

```
+------------+--------+----------+
| id_persona | opcion | COUNT(*) |
+------------+--------+----------+
|          1 | A      |        6 |
|          1 | B      |        2 |
+------------+--------+----------+
```

De una forma más compacta y combinando con los datos del evaluado, podrías mostrarlo también así:

```
SELECT nombre,
       apellido,
       grupo,
       email,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(
        opcion,':',n_respuestas
       ) ORDER BY opcion) resultados
  FROM personas JOIN (
    SELECT id_persona,opcion,
      COUNT(*) n_respuestas
      FROM respuestas
      GROUP BY 1,2
  ) c1 USING(id_persona)
  GROUP BY 1,2,3,4;

+---------------+----------------+-------+-------------------+------------+
| nombre        | apellido       | grupo | email             | resultados |
+---------------+----------------+-------+-------------------+------------+
| JOSE FERNANDO | LUCIANO GARCIA | D     | josep55@gmail.com | A:6,B:2    |
+---------------+----------------+-------+-------------------+------------+
```

Comment: David muchísimas gracias!!! Eso es lo que quiero, agradezco mucho tu tiempo, de verdad lo valoro bastante! Ya te cuento como me fue, ya entendí como tratarlo, gracias!!

Comment: Genial, entonces vamos a dejarlo bien rematado: [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)